# azure website restart and take old dll version

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc

One of my site is hosted on windows azure and when azure restart site from manage windows azure panel. then it take old version dll and site is down until we restart the site by deploying global.asax or change in web.config to restart the site.

after deployment of global.asax or change in web.config site is restart and then it work perfectly and take latest dll.

so if any issues with my code then it should not work after the restart by deploying global.asax file so i think issues is not from code side.

Error like "Could not load type 'DSF.DATA.Repository.RecurringOrderLogResposity' from 'DSF.DATA Version 1.0.0"

I am just deploying changed dll using FTP & site restart and take effect successfully

I have already resolve this error and uploaded latest dll too but when site restart from azure panel it back and then site down until i restart the site by deploying global.asax file so i think issues is not from code side.

please please help I am in big trouble as my site is live site and there are lot of traffic

Thanks Vipul

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is acting as designed with how .Net works. The same thing happens in IIS if you  upload a DLL and then stop, start, or restart the site it will not recompile and is running out of cache because it's all compiled into memory at first launch. It doesn't reference those DLL files again until a new compile is made. You're forcing the recompile by touching those files which is a trigger to IIS that somethings changed and to call it all again.

As a matter of practice, you should build into your deployment routine to upload the DLL, then touch the web.config and you shouldn't even need to stop, start, or restart the application. Does that help?

-Paul Drew